# Evitar reenvio de formulario laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-4

Tengo un formulario como el siguiente

```
  <form id="formD" class="ui form error" action="{{route('search')}}" method="post">
          <div class="field">
            <div class="ui fluid icon input">
              <input id="wname" name="wname" type="text" placeholder="Nombre Wi-Fi...">
              <i id="search" class="inverted circular search link icon"></i>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="field">
            <div class="ui checkbox">
              <input id="terms" type="checkbox" name="terms">
              <label>Acepto los terminos y condiciones.</label>
            </div>
        </div>
        {!! csrf_field() !!}
        <div class="ui error message" id="eSer"></div>
      </form>
```

Que solo pasa los parametros por post hacia el controlador este recibe los datos y los proceso y retorna en este caso de la siguiente maneral

```
return view('index',['wifis'=>$wifi]);
```

Y todo funciona bien, pero que pasa si el usuario da f5 en la vista que acabo de retornar le aparecerá un mensaje diciendo que si desea reenviar el formulario y quiero evitar eso que se podria hacer, se que se se solucionaría haciendo un redirect pero necesito que en la vista se muestre los datos que le estoy pasando a la vista que en este caso es la variable wifis.

Aclaracion

mis rutas son las siguientes

```
Route::get('/',[
    'uses'=>'Admin@indexView',
    'as'=>'index'
  ]);
  Route::post('/',[
    'uses'=>'Admin@indexSearch',
    'as'=>'search'
  ]);
```

Mis dos metodos controladores son

```
    public function indexView(){
          return view('index');
        }

        public function indexSearch(Request $request){
          //procesos
return view('index',['wifis'=>$wifi]);
          }
```

Comment: Si entendí bien, ¿la vista es la misma en ambos casos?

Comment: @Shaz Exacto...

Comment: La respuesta como sugieres es utilizar redirect,  pero sin ver tu controlador o los métodos implicados es difícil dar una respuesta concreta. Dado que dices que no puedes hacer redireccion algo no estas haciendo bien, segura mente el método que recibe el post este asumiendo competencias que no le corresponden.

Comment: @Xerif El controlador que recibe el post solo hace una consulta a la BD y solo debe retornar el resultado a la vista que es la misma de la cual se hace la petición y otro controlador que solo se encarga de devolver la vista.

Comment: @Xerif mira la actualización de la pregunta

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tal vez la forma más típica y sencilla es utilizar la sesión para almacenar los datos y obtenerlos así cuando se haga la redirección.

Asumo que hay una vista que muestra el formulario:

```
public function mostrar(...)
{
    // ...

    $wifis = []; // no sé que tipo de variable almacenes
    if (Session::has('wifis')) {
        $wifis = Session::get('wifis');
    }

    return view('index', compact('wifis'));
}
```

En el método del controlador que recibe el formulario:

```
public function recibir(...)
{
    // ...

    Session::put('wifis', $wifi);

    return redirect()->route('formulario2');
}
```

Entonces simplemente tienes dos rutas que dirigen al mismo método y controlador:

```
Route::get('ruta1', 'controlador@mostrar')->name('formulario');
Route::get('ruta2', 'controlador@mostrar')->name('formulario2');
```

Lo único que quedaría pendiente es como determinas cuando limpiar el valor de wifis almacenado en la sesión, pero ya depende de tu implementación y tu diseño.

Comment: Estoy utilizando la ultima version y en bastantes foros hablan que el middleware web no esta presente y por consiguiente la session no se preservara. Existe algun problema en eso con tu respuesta?

Comment: No entiendo, ¿acaso el middleware web no lo tienes incluido por defecto en todas tus rutas de web.php? Me refiero al RouteServiceProvider, Laravel lo hace por defecto, mira su código: https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/app/Providers/RouteServiceProvider.php#L45

Comment: Ese  middleware esta incluido en otros lados hablan del  middleware StartSession, olvidemos lo utlimo. Ahora he agregado una actualización a la pregunta ya que me diste una respuesta pero no utilizo un mismo metodo como controlado.

Comment: El middleware StartSession forma parte del grupo de middlewares web, también por defecto, a menos que tengas una implementación particular.

Comment: La respuesta que di responde perfectamente a la información que agregaste también. Simplemente debes agregar otro `Route::get()` para la redirección.

Comment: OK prefecto, de igual forma con tu respuesta cumpliria el siguiente requerimiento. El usuario puede hacer varias veces la peticion post y entonces al momento de verificar con Session::has la variabe ya estaria creada y mostraria información de la peticion anterior? o en momento de no hacer petición sino solo simplemente ingresar a la ruta por get se mostraria información de la petición anterior?.

Comment: La verdad y con todo respeto, esa parte te corresponde probarla y determinar si te sirve o no, por eso agregué el último párrafo donde te digo que depende del diseño de tu aplicación como administras las variables almacenadas en sesión, específicamente cuando borrarlas o no.